# Optimizing the declaration of variables in my project

Tags: c#-3.0

In my current project I am using 67 variables out of which few are string, int, decimal and bools.

I would like to optimize my declaration of code. I am using c#. What is the best way to do the declaration according to coding standards. It would be great if you can help me with an example.

Comment: 67 variables where in a method / function / class / a project / etc?  I've never heard of such a coding standard which states how many variables one can use or what one should use.

Comment: It's the octopus pattern

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very unclear, but from the sound of it, it kind of sounds like your variables are all lumped in one place, I'm assuming either as locals to `Main()` or fields in a single class?

If so the best advice we can give is remember your Single Responsibility Principle (SRP) and other good OOD techniques.

Your classes (and methods, etc) should be small enough to fulfill one and only one responsibility, any class (or method) that is that large is probably doing way too much.